# Difference between passing value directly to http request vs defining it before

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've got two functions here:

```js
// creates url /messages?data=undefined ->results into error
update1() {
  this.httpClient.get <any>> (
    this.dataService.url + '/messages?data=' + ( < any > window).settings.seq || '0', {
      headers: this.dataService.headers
    }
  ).subscribe((result: aby ) => {
    if (!result)
      return;

// ...
  }, (error: any) => {
    this.dataService.HandleError(error);
  });
}

// creates url /messages?data=0 -> works
update2() {
let seq = ( < any > window).settings.seq || '0';
  this.httpClient.get <any>> (
    this.dataService.url + '/messages?data=' + seq, {
      headers: this.dataService.headers
    }
  ).subscribe((result: aby ) => {
    if (!result)
      return;

// ...
  }, (error: any) => {
    this.dataService.HandleError(error);
  });
}
```

the first one doesn't work if `(<any>window).settings.seq` is undefined (it doesn't use '0' value), however if I define that as variable (like in the example `update2()`) it works fine and uses '0'.

This is probably a dumb question, but could someone explain me the difference? Shouldn't the first method work just fine?

Comment: It's about operator precedence: `+` is evaluated before `||`. You need to wrap that expression in parentheses.

Comment: `(( < any > window).settings.seq || '0')` should work then, right?

Comment: It should and will, yes.